# Improving audio quality in a low-power application

Tags: amplifier, audio, signal-processing

I am currently using a [TS4962IQT class D audio amplifier](http://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/4e/19/1b/1f/fc/43/49/b6/CD00045973.pdf/files/CD00045973.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00045973.pdf) to drive a mini speaker with 2W and 28mm in diameter.

The audio amplifier is used in combination with a STM32F051K8U6 microcontroller that has a 12 bit DAC.

**My question:**

How can I increase the audio quality of this setup without changing the microcontroller?

My idea was to use a so-called smart amplifier instead of the TS4962IQT mentioned above.
I found for example [this one](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/data-sheet/TFA9891_SDS.pdf).

Do you think such an amplifier would improve the sound quality? Has anyone gained experience with this kind of amplifier perhaps?

P.S.: I'm no expert in this field, so please apologize if my questions are a bit noobish.

Comment: Is there a particular aspect of the sound quality that needs improving? How is the speaker mounted: is it in a box of some sort?

Comment: First thing to improve any quality specification: measure the parameters you are intrested in and establish a specification for what the parameter should be.

Comment: When I play a sound file with the current setup, one can hear a quite loud noise.
The speaker is mounted in a little resonant chamber box.

Comment: I'd be more inclined to ask if the speaker is rated for 2W.

Comment: It is an 8 Ohm speaker that is rated at 2W. Furthermore, the amplifier is driven at 3.7 V, so the real power the amplifier delivers should be less than 2W.

Comment: The speaker should be upgraded. At little over an inch it will be crappy quality.

Comment: Unfortunately, this isn't possible as the speaker isn't allowed  to have more than 28mm in diameter for this application.

Comment: Easy. Bigger speaker. Experimentally, anyway,  a 4" speaker in a baffle or enclosure will demonstrate that the speaker is the biggest limitation in quality, then you can argue for more space. If you don't win the argument, that's too bad. You could experiment with 4 ocf the current speakers in series--parallel to see if it's an improvement.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it has been abandoned for over two years by the asker

Answer (score 2):

> How can I increase the audio quality of this setup without changing the microcontroller?

First find out where the problem lies. The data sheet quotes

> Output power: 1.4 W at 5 V or 0.5 W at 3.0 V
>   into 8 Ω with 1% THD+N maximum.

- Connect the output to a reasonable quality regular sized 8 Ω loudspeaker and listen.
- Turn the volume up gradually and try to detect at what level it distorts. Make a note of the setting. Assuming the speaker is adequately rated then at this level the amplifier is maxed out.
- Reconnect to your small speaker.
- Turn the volume up gradually to the point of distortion.

If the small speaker distorts at a lower setting than the large one then the problem is the speaker. If it goes as high as the big speaker then your amp is the limiting factor.

Make your next step based on the results of the above experiments.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I'll try that soon.

What I already noticed is that there's also some noise when no sound file is played. It's a kind of background noise.

This may be due to the very tiny size of the board the amplifier is located on (because of perturbations coming from other parts). But unfortunately, the board size is limited to the current one.